# Powershell to get the web element value info as a variable

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to get the ServiceNow data in to an variable with using PowerShell and Selenium Chrome Driver. But I don't know the right way to get it. I am trying to get the marked data but i can't.
The below method is not working:

```
$Chromedriver.FindelementByTagName('input').getAttribute('value')
```

Could you anyone can help me ?

Snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *`FindelementByTagName`* you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using [*CSS_SELECTOR*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447):

  ```
  $Chromedriver.FindElementByCssSelector("input[aria-label='Opened']").getAttribute('value')
  ```
- Using [XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

  ```
  $Chromedriver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@aria-label='Opened']").getAttribute('value')
  ```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Find the span text, if parent div text has certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70228481/7429447)